# Prestashop hook and override module

Tags: module, overriding, hook, prestashop

I created a hook and I want to move there a module. I override the FrontController.php within the override folder (override/clases/controller/FrontController.php).

```
self::$smarty->assign(array(
‘HOOK_HEADER’ => Module::hookExec(‘header’),
‘HOOK_TOP’ => Module::hookExec(‘top’),
‘HOOK_NEWHOOK’ => Module::hookExec(‘DisplayNewHook’),
‘HOOK_LEFT_COLUMN’ => Module::hookExec(‘leftColumn’)
));
```

Then I edited the php file module to add:

```
function hookNewHook($params) { return $this->hookTop( $params ); }
```

And it works correctly. But is not there another way to do this? Because if the module is updated, the changes will be lost.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Module overriding is not possible until now. What you can do is to create a duplicate module (copying pasting :) ) and use that module with your changes. Any core module(s) you modify may lost the changes when you update the prestashop.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find some help for creating a PrestaShop module there : http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS14/Creating+a+PrestaShop+module